# How to create Materialize 1.0.0-rc.2 dropdown sub menus?

Tags: css, materialize

I have found how to create dropdown sub menus for older versions of Materialize (v. 0.100). But the new 1.0.0 version seems to have made some changes regards to this. Any ideas how one would create a dropdown sub-menu like this?

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ah39.png)